# How do I set default properties for ALL console windows?

Tags: windows, console

Right-click-->Properties does not apply to other console windows - only to ones with same name (i.e. cmd.exe).
Can I do this for ALL console windows?

Comment: There has been a question on Stackoverflow answering the same question: [Windows default size for console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288255/windows-default-size-for-console-application)

Answer (score 4):

Summary of the [link (just in case it gets lost):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288255/windows-default-size-for-console-application)

- Settings are stored in Registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
- Or right-click on the title bar of a console window, in the drop down menu click "Defaults".